# PHP: Convert $_POST into variable?

Tags: php, variables, post

I'm building a form that's in a loop, so that the user can choose how many rows they want to put into the database. And all my input-names have this value `art_$i` where `$i` is the number of the rows, that my loop generates.

When the form-button is pressed, I then try to pull out the value of each `$_POST['art_X']` by creating a second loop that repeats itself the same amount of times as my `$i` loop that is naming by inputs as `art_1`, `art_2`, `art_3` etc. This second loop I call `$b`, here's how I try to solve the problem.. It just isn't working at all!

```
$convert_post_to_variable = "$_POST[art_" . $b . "]";
```

Any suggestions on how I could solve this problem, would be MUCH APPRECIATED! :-D

Comment: Your description is cryptic to me.
 More code would be a help. The line you posted $convert_post_to_variable = "$_POST[art_" . $b . "]"; 
creates a string variable with the contents "$_POST..." - that is probably not what you want (remove the outside quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes around variable names.  It makes a mess of things, and then you would have to use curly brackets... just don't do it.  You can use an arbitrary string key on an associative array like this:

```
$convert_post_to_variable = $_POST['art_' . $b];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$convert_post_to_variable = $_POST[ 'art_' . $b ];
```